# Is $\mathbb{Q}_2$ complete?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, prime-numbers, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Is the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ complete respect to the $p$-adic norm $|\cdot|_p$ when $p=2$?

Comment: Isn't it _defined_ as the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to $\lvert\,\cdot\,\rvert_2$?

Comment: What do you think the notation $\mathbf Q_p$ *means*?

Answer (score 2):

Why you went to ask this question depends on which definition of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ you started with, but the answer doesn't : there are 3 definitions

- one from $\Bbb{Z}_p=\varprojlim \Bbb{Z/p^n Z}$ (limits of sequences of integers that converge $\bmod p^n$ for all $n$, ie. for $|.|_p$) and $\Bbb{Q}_p=\Bbb{Z}_p[p^{-1}]$
- one from the rules of addition/multiplication on $p$-adic series $\sum_{n\ge -N} a_n p^n,a_n\in 0\ldots p-1$
- one as the completion of $\Bbb{Q}$ for the $p$-adic absolute value (similar to that $\Bbb{R}$ is the completion of $\Bbb{Q},|.|_\infty$)

Thus the answer is to prove that they are all equivalent. The reasoning doesn't depend on the chosen $p$ prime.